# Is it possible to rewrite previous line in console?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create process animation in my console app. Is it possible to rewrite previous lines for this needs? I know about `\r` but it works only with current line.

If it is not possible, how could I achieve animation effect? Thanks.

*My console is standard Ubuntu 12.04 terminal emulator.*

---

Thanks to @MrSmith42 I made this simple demo, which shows way to overwrite lines:

```
public class Flush {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("**********************************");
        }
        // ESC[5A - cursor up 5 times
        // \r - cursor return to begin of line
        // ESC[J - erase to end of screen
        System.out.print("\033[5A\r\033[J");
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("##################################");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends on your console. Lot of consols support  [vt100 commands](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) which allow e.g. changing the position of the cursor or change he color of text or background.

I use it a lot to make colored debug output in my java programs to the shell.

If the link is dead use this google search
https://www.google.de/search?q=vt100+comands&oq=vt100+comands

Comment: Could you demonstrate short demo? My console is standard Ubuntu 12.04 terminal emulator.

Comment: As simple color-test, try `System.out.println("Hallo \033[32mgreen\033[0m-text.")`

Comment: It works. Thanks, I'll try to archive animation issue using it. +1

Comment: @zvzdhk: post a comment if it works (maybe even an example). I never tried other commands than color related ones.

Comment: Links are dead again.

Comment: @Rasmus Hansen: updated the link and added a search-link for everyone who cannot use a search-web-site by them self.